# How to determine the event came from the main document of the tab

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm developing an extension for Firefox. The extension adds event listener to "appcontent" element on "load" event.

How to determine the event came from the main document of the tab? At the moment all events from different elements of the page come (for example image and even the extension document if it fires one). I would like to exclude all the cases, including frames, iframe and so on, only the url typed in the location bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just an answer for those who gave points to the question itself and who might find the question through the search.

The task is solved with the line

```
  if (Event.originalTarget == content.document)
```

worked for me.

Found in some newsgroup

Comment: Note, that this restricts you to the currently visible page. I.e. if a background page finishes loading, it will not pass this check.

Comment: I like the approach #1 at https://forums.addons.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=124 better, even though the author claims it doesn't always work. The best solution would be to pick apart a working relatively popular extension and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare `event.srcElement.ownerDocument` the main page document?  You could also use the .location.href properties.  Quick and dirty example:

```
//- on event
var doc = event.srcElement.ownerDocument;
if (doc && (doc.location.href == currentUrl))
    runFunction();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.ownerDocument

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `originalTarget` and `explicitOriginalTarget` attributes of `event` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.originalTarget

Use it as something like:

```
if(event.explicitOriginalTarget == theHookedObject) {    
   // do your stuff 
}
```

Where `theHookedObject` is the object to which you've attached your listener to.